# ¿Cómo busco una letra en una cadena sin importar las tildes en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy intentando contar el número de letra que se repite en una cadena sin importar las mayúsculas, minúsculas o tildes. Este es mi código:

```
def buscar_letra(cadena, letra_B):
    import unicodedata
    unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', cadena).encode('ascii','ignore')
    cont=0
    for letra in cadena: 
        lB=letra_B.upper()
        l=letra.upper()
        if l == lB :
            cont=cont+1
    return(cont)

cadena=(u"raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')")
letra_b=(u"raw_input('introduzca la letra: ')")
```

la cuestión es que no me reconoce y cuando lo ejecuto me da de resultado 0 ni siquiera me pide la cadena y la letra para buscar. No sé si estoy poniendo de manera correcta la parte de unicodedata

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ni siquiera me pide la cadena y la letra para buscar.

La manera de almacenar el contenido de un `raw_input()` en una varaible, es haciendo una asignación de esta función a una variable. De cualquier manera se mostrará las solicitud de datos.

```
cadena = raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')
letra_b = raw_input('introduzca la letra: ')
```

> la cuestión es que no me reconoce y cuando lo ejecuto me da de resultado 0

Es muy probable que la causa de esto sea el hecho de nunca está invocando la función, se deseas visualizar el resultado debes usar `print` ya que la función retorna un resultado: `return(cont)`

```
print buscar_letra(cadena,letra_b)
```

Una recomendación, por convención se importan los módulos al principio del archivo.

Un código adecuado:

```
import unicodedata

def buscar_letra(cadena, letra_B):
    unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u"{}".format(cadena)).encode('ascii','ignore')
    cont = 0
    for letra in cadena: 
        lB = letra_B.upper()
        l = letra.upper()
        if l == lB :
            cont = cont + 1

    return(cont)

cadena = raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')
letra_b = raw_input('introduzca la letra: ')

print buscar_letra(cadena,letra_b)
```

Hay que notar que el casting a unicode lo hago en la misma función así: `u"{}".format(cadena)`, pero es igual de válido hacerlo en el mismo `raw_input()`.

Un ejemplo de ejecución:

```
introduzca la cadena: zanahoria
introduzca la letra: a
3
```

Espero te haya ayudado, saludos!

Comment: La probe usando la siguiente cadena (espero que se vea bien, son todas las variaciones de las vocales con acentos): "aeiouáéíóúàèìòùâêîôûäëïöüAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÄËÏÖÜ", y busque la letra "a". Yo cuento 10 ocurrencias. ¿Qué resultados te da a ti?

Comment: El còdigo falla al buscar dentro de una cadena con acentos. Probe con "María ama a Toño", buscando la letra "a".

Comment: Falta asignar a `cadena` el resultado de `unicodedata.normalize`. Y para el _casting_ a unicode mejor si se usa la función `unicode()`.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, en

```
cadena=(u"raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')")
letra_b=(u"raw_input('introduzca la letra: ')")
```

estas simplemente asignando dos string, no ejecutando un input, que sería asi:

```
cadena=raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')
letra_b=raw_input('introduzca la letra: ')
```

Tampoco llamas a la función `buscar_letra` ...

El resto del código, reordenado y con casos de prueba

```
import unicodedata

def buscar_letra(cadena, letra_B):
    cadena = unicode(cadena, "utf8")
    cadena = ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', cadena)
                     if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
    return cadena.upper().count(letra_B.upper())
```

**Prueba interactiva**

Usando este código para la prueba por teclado:

```
cadena = raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')
letra_b = raw_input('introduzca la letra: ')

print buscar_letra(cadena,letra_b)
```

probamos ingresando la frase "María ama a Toño",

```
candid@dell ~ $ python search.py 
introduzca la cadena: María ama a Toño
introduzca la letra: a
5
```

Otra más

```
candids@dell ~ $ python search.py 
introduzca la cadena: María ama a Toño
introduzca la letra: i
1
```

**Edición**

Agrega conversión de str a unicode para textos ingresados por teclado bajo Python 2.7

Corrige código de Python 3 a Python 2.7

Comment: Si te fijas la pregunta es de Python 2.7, lo que dices *estas simplemente asignando dos string, no ejecutando un input, que sería asi:*, simplemente es que en Python 2.7 así funcionan los "inputs".

Comment: @gcoronel99 . `cadena=(u"raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')")` también es una cadena en Python 2.7 (está encerrado entre cremillas), Lo que si funciona es `cadena=raw_input('introduzca la cadena: ')` (sin las cremillas).

Comment: Es un casting de unicode

Answer (score 0):

El codigo completo es como sigue

```
def buscar_letra(cadena, letra_B):
    import unicodedata

    norm_string = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', cadena)
    norm_string = u''.join(ch for ch in norm_string if unicodedata.category(ch) != 'Mn')

    cont=0
    for letra in norm_string: 
        lB=letra_B.upper()
        l=letra.upper()
        if l == lB :
            cont=cont+1
    return(cont)

cadena=input("introduzca la cadena: ")
letra_b=input("introduzca la letra: ")

conteo=buscar_letra(cadena, letra_b)
print ("Conteo:",conteo)
```

Comment: El còdigo falla al buscar dentro de una cadena con acentos. Probe con "María ama a Toño", buscando la letra "a".